# Error when installing any MiKTeX package: file="...\mpm.ini", line="19732", error="the configuration file is not signed"

Tags: errors, packages, miktex

When trying to install a package (specifically lastpage but it's the same with any I've tried to install), I get an error.
In the error report I get:

> "A MiKTeX configuration file could not be loaded."

with details:

> file="C:\Users\xxNAMExx\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
> 2.9\miktex/config\mpm.ini", line="19732", error="the configuration file is not signed".

I can't seem to find any reference to this error in online documentation.

I'm hoping someone can help me with this error!

64-bit / Windows 10

Comment: check for updates (in admin mode and user mode) first. miktex had some problems in the last days. If this doesn't help open an issue at the github tracker of miktex.

Comment: when I try to check for updates I get the same error when pointing to the package directory, and I get a different error when opting to check for updates from the internet. "A connection to api2.miktex.org could not be established.

More info: https://miktex.org/kb/fix-couldnt-connect"

Comment: if you are installing from a local repository can't you update this repository in whatever way you did setup it the first time?

Comment: My local repository is a shared drive that was created by someone else (at work) so I wouldn't know how to update the repository. If i reinstall with the latest .exe will this act as an 'update'?

Comment: sorry but your system is a unknown state (and unknown age) and I can't give you an advice what to do.

Comment: Newer MiKTeX versions cannot cope with old repositories. This was a breaking. See here: https://miktex.org/announcement/miktex-2-9-7440